# Qt error while including <windows.h>

Tags: windows, qt, include

How can I use windows.h in Qt application? After including it I get several errors like

```
c:\Qt\4.4.3\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_windows.h:387: error:    
declaration of C function 'long int InterlockedCompareExchange(long int*, long int,    
 long int)' conflicts with    
d:\old\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/winbase.h:1681: error:    
previous declaration 'LONG InterlockedCompareExchange(volatile LONG*, LONG,    
 LONG)' here
```

All includes in order:

```
windows.h    
iostream    
QtCore    
QtGui    
QObject    
QString    
QFile    
QProcess    
QIODevice
```

EDIT: Problem disappear, `Process.start()` is now working, but I'm unable to say, what change made the difference.

EDIT2: It's not that simple. I'll create new question.

EDIT3: The same code `QProcess Process; Process.start("notepad.exe");` works in `main()` and doesn't work in function called as a slot. Works only `QProcess *Process = new QProcess(); Process->start("notepad.exe");`

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need to include `windows.h` in a Qt application?

Comment: QProcess Process; Process.start("notepad.exe"); throws QProcess::UnknownError. Therefore I need to use WinExec() or system().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its worth debugging why QProcess throws a QProcess::UnknownError - switching to use the native API directly does make the whole point of using QT - its cross platform afterall - a bit of a joke.

You are doing something that *should* work, that probably uses WinExec or system() already and as such, your attempt to launch notepad will just fail again.

Perhaps QT just needs the full path to notepad.exe? There are definitely times to write platform code in QT, this isn't one of them.

Comment: "Perhaps QT just needs the full path to notepad.exe?" No, this doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a stand alone QT program? or is it running in some kind of restricted mode on Vista/Windows 7? The only error I know of that CreateProcess might return is if the launch requires UAC elevation. But notepad.exe should not. So there has to be something else systematically wrong with your sample.

Comment: Im curious-  if you have the debug build of Qt it should be able to show you the entire call stack at the time the QProcess::Error got thrown. It should be failing on the basis of an error code returned from CreateProcess...

Comment: 1)Standalone program.   2)No, program not fails, but in LineEdit appears "5" after executing program with code "    QProcess Process;    Process.start("notepad.exe");    gMw->leBrowserPath->setText(QString::number(Process.error()));    
"    even without error. Strange.

Comment: But it pointed me in right direction. If anybody wants to dig this deeper they can ask the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper version of mingw for your version of Qt. Qt 4.3 is not compatible with mingw >= 4

Comment: MinGW version is 3.15.2, Qt version is 4.4.3

Comment: But includes are from mingw 4: d:\old\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/winbase.h:1681: error:

Comment: Indeed. I used information from file MinGW\include\_mingw.h which is wrong for some reason.